# create alias with argument

Tags: bash

I want an alias that produce folowing result:

```
$cd /home/ok

[clear screen]
/home/ok
total 452K
-rwx--x--x 1 user gigl  16K Oct  1 14:08 ok0
drwx------ 5 user gigl    0 Oct  1 14:02 ok1
drwx------ 5 user gigl    0 Oct  1 13:59 ok2
drwx------ 9 user gigl    0 Oct  1 14:01 ok3
-rw------- 1 user gigl   32 Sep 30 14:36 ok4
```

I did a script like

```
$cat ~/.cd.sh
#!/bin/bash
cd $1 && clear && pwd && ls -lh --color=auto
```

But it does not change the current dir. This is probably because in the script it will change the dir but when it goes back to bash I'm back in the dir I executed the script.

Any idea ?

Thanks, from answers I got something like that working great:

```
alias ls="clear && pwd && ls -lh --color=auto"
cd() { builtin cd "$1" && ls; }
```

Comment: I wanted to reuse the term "cd", in that way I believe it's an alias, improperly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally, I'd recommend writing a function rather than an alias loaded from  your .bashrc or .bash_profile.

The function would look pretty much like what you've already got:

```
cdd () {
  cd "$1"
  clear
  pwd
  ls -lh --color=auto
}
```

I'm not positive why the alias causes you to go back, but I tested the function and it works.

Comment: I think the question wasn't clear.  His script went back, and he can't figure out how to get an argument into an alias.  As you say, a function is the proper solution.

Comment: For standards compliance, avoid the `function` keyword. Use a syntax like `cdd(){ }`. If you do that, and replace `$1` by `"$1` (for directories with whitespace), you'll get a +1 from me.

Comment: Great worked, I wrote this function in my .bash_profile, but I cant alias so it become only cd because it give me an infinite loop :-(

Comment: @Guillaume: Change the line from `cd "$1"` to `builtin cd "$1"` to prevent the infinite loop. You also don't need to alias it, just call the function `cd`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function instead, for example

```
mycd() { cd "${1?}" && clear && pwd && ls -lh --color=auto; }
```

Comment: The question mark causes an error if no parameter is passed. It is not as pretty as a manual check but yields shorter code :)

Comment: builtin cd does not generate error with no params. this could be usefull not to clear the screen. The ? normally mean optional, it's crazy they throw an error for that. I would except not having an error at all.

Comment: I suppose `cd "$@"` would be more useful than the other proposals.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want && either. This will run each command simultaneously, iirc. You should use semicolons.

Comment: No, it doesn't run them simultaneously - it runs each one conditionally on the success of the preceding one. A single ampersand would run them in the background.

Comment: You're correct. Semicolons would run them regardless of the previous exit status.